# Create a table in SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, svg

I'm trying to create a table-like object within an SVG document. Currently, due to the fact that SVG does not have a table element, I am using an HTML parser to go through and convert an HTML table, (created by the user in an HTML table Builder), to a group of SVG objects, and then adding that to my overall SVG drawing. I was wondering if any one was able to find a better alternative to this method, such as an SVG table builder? I'm looking to accomplish this using Javascript or jquery.  Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I would simply embed a real table in my SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <foreignObject x="10" y="10" width="100" height="150">
    <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <table><!-- ... --></table>
    </body>
  </foreignObject>
  <!-- ... -->
</svg>
```

Comment: This is actually a very good idea. However, I have one problem in that I cannot use a foreignobject element. It's hard to explain, but I have created a custom SVG canvas object, and I need the table to be rendered using SVG not HTML, (or XHTML). Also, would this cause problems when using the svg image? If I define the table in HTML, won't it fail to scale properly, as it is not in vector format?

Comment: Another variant of this is to overlay an svg element on a plain table, e.g. if you just want to draw arrows across cells. That way you can combine svg with a table without using foreignobject.  

But the original question is still a good one, and my use case today is that I want to bring a table into inkscape for use in a bigger diagram.

Comment: ForeignObject support in chrome is really shaky. Its a shame. I had to resort to using native svg elements to achieve many thing because of this. For starters there are some rendering bugs. If you drag a foreign object around it will leave shadows, which go away after page scroll but are distracting to the core. SVG transforms do not apply to foreign object elements in chrome. this is not the case with firefox though.

Comment: Foreign object is not supported by any ie version. Recently ran into the same issue.  Look into using group (g), text and tspand an alternative.

Comment: `foreignobject` should be spelt `foreignObject`.

Comment: @Shane Thank you. I am surprised that the incorrect casing lived in this answer for almost 5 years. :)

Answer (score 27):

**U can use  this way:**

There are no 'table'-type elements in SVG, but you can achieve a similar visual and interactive effect using the 'text' and 'tspan' elements. On the left are 2 such tabular representations, the top one with columnar layout (that is, the user can select all the text in a column), and the bottom table with row- based layout. An obvious disadvantage to this approach is that you cannot create a table with both vertical and horizontal selectivity. A less obvious flaw is that creating a tabular appearance does not confer the semantic qualities of a real table, which is disadvantageous to accessibility and is not conducive to rich interactivity and navigation

Example:

```
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='no'?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN'
  'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd'>
<svg width='100%' height='100%' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'>

   <title>SVG Table</title>

   <g id='columnGroup'>
      <rect x='65' y='10' width='75' height='110' fill='gainsboro'/>
      <rect x='265' y='10' width='75' height='110' fill='gainsboro'/>

      <text x='30' y='30' font-size='18px' font-weight='bold' fill='crimson'>
         <tspan x='30' dy='1.5em'>Q1</tspan>
         <tspan x='30' dy='1em'>Q2</tspan>
         <tspan x='30' dy='1em'>Q3</tspan>
         <tspan x='30' dy='1em'>Q4</tspan>
      </text>

      <text x='100' y='30' font-size='18px' text-anchor='middle'>
         <tspan x='100' font-weight='bold' fill='crimson'>Sales</tspan>
         <tspan x='100' dy='1.5em'>$ 223</tspan>
         <tspan x='100' dy='1em'>$ 183</tspan>
         <tspan x='100' dy='1em'>$ 277</tspan>
         <tspan x='100' dy='1em'>$ 402</tspan>
      </text>

      <text x='200' y='30' font-size='18px' text-anchor='middle'>
         <tspan x='200' font-weight='bold' fill='crimson'>Expenses</tspan>
         <tspan x='200' dy='1.5em'>$ 195</tspan>
         <tspan x='200' dy='1em'>$ 70</tspan>
         <tspan x='200' dy='1em'>$ 88</tspan>
         <tspan x='200' dy='1em'>$ 133</tspan>
      </text>

      <text x='300' y='30' font-size='18px' text-anchor='middle'>
         <tspan x='300' font-weight='bold' fill='crimson'>Net</tspan>
         <tspan x='300' dy='1.5em'>$ 28</tspan>
         <tspan x='300' dy='1em'>$ 113</tspan>
         <tspan x='300' dy='1em'>$ 189</tspan>
         <tspan x='300' dy='1em'>$ 269</tspan>
      </text>
   </g>
</svg>
```

Source: http://svg-whiz.com/svg/table.svg

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has written a JavaScript/D3 plug-in that generates tables using svg.g objects?

Comment: One major difference between an SVG table constructed like this, vs a <table> constructed in plain HTML, is that this SVG table is column-oriented, whereas HTML table  is row-oriented.

Comment: @TheRedPea: on the linked page, you can also see an row-oriented variant.

Comment: Mozilla has a good reference to the tspan element at [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan).

Comment: This is good, but is there any published thought on how to decide, from the input data, how wide/tall a given table should be? I need to construct tables in a similar way, and can do so if they're of a fixed size, but what I really need to do is find ways of fitting my table text into a tabular form that's aesthetically "neat" and employs word-wrap and other finesses. Only after figuring all that out can I arrive at a final size.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar need and was not able to find a suitable tool for automatically building an SVG image to display tabular data (the tools I could find via Google produced illegible or otherwise unusable results) so I built my own. You or anyone else who lands on this page while searching for such a tool may find it helpful:

https://topherrhodes.com/svg-table/

This tool uses a CSV as input, so if you have to go from an HTML table you could modify the script to convert the table to a JavaScript object, or generate a CSV as an intermediate step.

Generally, I agree with the other users here who have brought up how SVG is not a good format for displaying tabular data and that for usability and compatibility you should opt to use an actual HTML table whenever possible. But there may be certain cases where that's not possible.

Comment: Nice tool, looks useful - I've a question though - how do you decide the dimensions of the output table? And as an extension of that question, is there a word-wrap option for cells that contain excessively long contents?

Comment: @ThomasKimber The width of each column is determined by the width of the longest data within that column, which varies based on the font and font size, this is found using getComputedTextLength() and iterating through each row and comparing the sizes to find the widest. There's no maximum column width and/or text wrapping as my assumption was that kind of data is not suitable for a table. This could be added by specifying a maximum width and calculating the height of each row by the tallest cell after text-wrapping is done. As it is, the height of each row is only based on font size+padding.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add my thoughts on this for posterity. There are a lot of fairly complicated options out there but if you just want something which *looks* like a table, this might get you started...

```
//assuming you have a table with an ID of src_table
var my_svg = '<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg_table" width="'+$("#src_table").width()+'px" height="'+$("#src_table").height()+'px">'
var table_offset = $('#src_table').offset();
$('#src_table').find('td').each(function() {
        //Add a rectangle for each <td> in the same place in SVG as the <td> is in relation to the top left of where the table is on page
        my_svg += '<rect x="'+(this_offset.left - table_offset.left)+'" y="'+(this_offset.top - table_offset.top)+'" width="'+$(this).width()+'" height="'+$(this).height()+'" stroke="black" stroke-width="'+$(this).css('border-width').replace('px','')+'"/>';

       //Text is assumed to be in a <p> tag. If it's not, just use the .html() of the <td> element
       (this).children('p').each(function(){
                t_offset = $(this).offset();
                var this_text = '<text x="'+(t_offset.left - table_offset.left)+'" y="'+(t_offset.top - table_offset.top)+'"  style="font-size:'+$(this).css('font-size')+'; fill: #ffffff">';
                    // Look for <br> tags and split them onto new lines.
                    var this_lines = $(this).html().split('<br>');
                    for(var i=0;i<this_lines.length;i++){
                        this_text += '<tspan x="'+(t_offset.left - table_offset.left)+'" dy="'+$(this).css('font-size')+'">'+this_lines[i]+'</tspan>';
                    }
            this_text += '</text>';
            my_svg +=  this_text;
        })
    }
});
my_svg += '</svg>';

//Either append my_svg to a div or pass the code onto whatever else you need to do with it.
```

This is obviously rough but might get you started down the right track.

Answer (score 1):

I found a project on github which automatically generates an HTML-like table from a JavaScript data structure: https://github.com/cocuh/SVG-Table

Since it does not rely on foreignObject, it's portability across browsers is much better.

Comment: Quote from the README: *Deprecated: highly recommend not to use this library*

Comment: That was deprecated September 7, 2019. Thanks for alerting people, I'll consider how yo update the answer but with the recent Stackoverflow leadership changes ny desire to contribute here is much lower.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example showing an SVG [foreignobject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) which contains a tabular layout of nested SVG elements. It only works in Chrome though.

It includes an HTML [table](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp) layout and a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) layout using div elements.

A jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XmC2A/1/).

```
<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <g id="shape">
            <rect x="0" y="0" rx="5" ry="5" width="100%" height="100%" fill="inherit" />
            <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="8" fill="yellow" />
        </g>
    </defs>
    <foreignobject width="100%" height="50px" y="0">

        <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <div style="height:20px">
                            <svg>
                                <use xlink:href="#shape" fill="CornflowerBlue" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div style="height:20px">
                            <svg>
                                <use xlink:href="#shape" fill="SlateBlue" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div style="height:20px">
                            <svg>
                                <use xlink:href="#shape" fill="SlateBlue" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div style="height:20px">
                            <svg>
                                <use xlink:href="#shape" fill="SlateBlue" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </foreignobject>
    <foreignobject width="100%" height="50px" y="60">

        <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column">
                <div>
                    <div style="height:20px;padding:2px">
                        <svg>
                            <use xlink:href="#shape" fill="orange" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;align-items:stretch">
                    <div style="width:33.333%;height:20px;padding:2px">
                        <svg>
                            <use xlink:href="#shape" fill="forestgreen" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                    <div style="width:33.333%;height:20px;padding:2px">
                        <svg>
                            <use xlink:href="#shape" fill="forestgreen" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                    <div style="width:33.333%;height:20px;padding:2px">
                        <svg>
                            <use xlink:href="#shape" fill="forestgreen" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </foreignobject>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Necromancing.
The trouble is, when you need a table that can have an indefinite amount of rows and columns, with an unknown and variable row-height, as well as texts unknown at compile-time, that needs to resize to fit into a container, and which should neither be clipped nor overflow.

Fortunately, I've found the solution ! 
It requires setting the viewBox at runtime with JavaScript, though.
Works in Firefox and Chrome.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Evacuation Plan</title>
        
        <style type="text/css">
        /*<![CDATA[*/
            
            .A4 
            { 
                width: 21cm; 
                height: 29.7cm;
            } 
            
        /*]]>*/
        </style>
        
    </head>
    <body class="A4">
        <div id="positionRoot" style="position: relative;">
        
        <div id="sizerForTable" style="position: absolute; display: block; top: 2.5cm; left: 5cm; width: 2.5cm; height: 2.5cm; background-color: hotpink;">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 0 0" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" width="100%" height="100%" >
              
              <rect id="rectBG" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" fill="#FF0000" />
              <foreignObject id="foTableContainer" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
                <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                  
                  <!--
                  <style type="text/css">
                  /*<![CDATA[*/
                        
                        .testTableLayout 
                        { 
                            font-size: 5px; 
                            line-height: 1em; 
                        } 
                        
                  /*]]>*/
                  </style>
                  -->
                  
                  <!-- also: Tabelle ausmessen - dies in Viewbox - dann verkleiners sich automatisch -->
                  
                  <table id="tblTest" class="testTableLayout" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: none;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr style="background-color: orange;">
                        <td>Row1</td>
                        <td>C1.2</td>
                        <td>Test<br />Me<br />More</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row2</td>
                        <td>C2.2</td>
                        <td>Test<!--&nbsp;Me&nbsp;More--></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row3</td>
                        <td>C3.2</td>
                        <td>Test</td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row4</td>
                        <td>C4.2</td>
                        <td>Test</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row5</td>
                        <td>C5.2</td>
                        <td>Test</td>
                    </tr>
                    <!--
                    -->
                    
                  </table>
                  
                  <script type="text/javascript">
                    //<![CDATA[
                    
                    (function () {
                        
                        var tbl = document.getElementById("tblTest"); 
                        var bg = document.getElementById("rectBG"); 
                        var nvb = ["0", "0", Math.ceil(tbl.offsetWidth).toString(), Math.ceil(tbl.offsetHeight).toString()]; 
                        
                        bg.setAttribute("width", nvb[2]); 
                        bg.setAttribute("height", nvb[3]); 
                        document.getElementById("foTableContainer").ownerSVGElement.setAttribute("viewBox", nvb.join(" ") ); 
                        
                        // console.log("newViewBox:", nvb); 
                        // console.log("w,h:", tbl.offsetWidth, tbl.offsetHeight); 
                        // console.log(document.getElementById("foTableContainer").ownerSVGElement.getAttribute("viewBox")); 
                    })();
                    
                    //]]>
                  </script>
                  
                </body>
              </foreignObject>
            </svg>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```