# SVG doesnt display anything on Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I am trying to create table with following code. I am beginner in Java Script and other libraries. Below code gets reflected in Console but UI doesn’t show anything. I am using d3 to create SVG. I am not sure is this correct way to mix D3 and jquery. Could anyone suggest what is right approach.

I have a table which has fixed number of entries. In below code Object is JSON Object.

```
var svg = d3.select(el[0])
.each(function() { this.focus(); })
.append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);


svg.append("text")
.attr("x", 0.5*width)  
.attr("y", 36)
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
.style("font-size", "36px") 
.style("text-decoration", "underline")  
.text(description);

var div=svg.append("div")
.attr("id","table");
var table = $('<table></table>').addClass('ex1');

var row = $('<tr></tr>').text('Device Name: ' +  Object.id);
table.append(row);
var row = $('<tr></tr>').text('Type: ' + Object.type);
table.append(row);
var row = $('<tr></tr>').text('IP Address: ' +Object.ipAddress);
table.append(row);
$('#table').append(table);
```

With above code I can see below elements in DOM Object.

```
*<svg width="1413" height="695">
    <text x="706.5" y="36" text-anchor="middle" style="font-size: 36px; text-decoration: underline;">
        Details Information for management1
    </text>
    <div id="table">
        <table class="ex1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    Device Name: mg1
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    Type: Sw
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    IP Address: 1.1.1.1
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</svg>*
```

I can see  Details Information for management1 on UI but not other elements.

Thanks

Comment: Try using your browser's developer tools to look at the DOM that results from the code, this is often useful for debugging purposes.  If this doesn't help, try copying the SVG from the DOM and adding it to your question, or - even better, set up a working example on, say, JSFiddle

Comment: your code is creating an html table, which is invalid within an svg.  You can simply change the svg and text elements to divs, and it should display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML elements, like `<div>` and `<table>`, are not valid SVG elements.  It is possible to embed HTML inside SVG using the `<foreignObject>` SVG element.  But you can't use them directly, like you are attempting here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are intended to create a table in svg, there is already an answer in stackoverflow:

[Create a table in SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987005/create-a-table-in-svg)