# Keep aspect ratio of table

Tags: css, html-table

I have a table representing coordinates.
[image: table with coordinates]

How can I have the size dynamically changing, so it always fits the parent div (width: 100%), like an image would?

Right now I use @media queries, which are hardcoded.
But there must be a better way.

```
.hitbox {
  width: 25%; /* of page */
}

@media (min-width: 702px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  .hitbox .tablewrapper {
    font-size: 9px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 840px) {
  .hitbox .tablewrapper {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 840px) and (max-width: 915px) {
  .hitbox .tablewrapper {
    font-size: 11px;
  }
}
```

**edit:**

The problem if the table needs to get even smaller then the text containing is fixed text size.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ucoLcm50/4/)
This works fine.
[image: Wide]
[image: narrow]
But smaller then that, It doen't work.
[image: fail]
It should make the font smaller, or at least cut each of the the cells (not the table).

**edit 2:**
The whole table should be visible all the time, it is not important to read the text, but to see the pattern (with colors gray or red) it creates.

**edit 3:**
The importance are the colors here, not the labels, so cutting the table and making it scrolling is not a solution here. It is required that like a heat map it is always completely visible.

Comment: Creating the table as [svg image](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17460908/3423324) was an Idea that came to mind, but it seems to complex, and I am not quite sure if it really scales like a normal image does.

Comment: Add scroll (horizontal), and button to scroll to left or right. And for font use vw / vh.

Comment: @MuhammadZaid Can you elaborate that more? You mean with Javascript?

Comment: Setting width and height in vw units works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [viewport-relative units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) for your font-size.

> `1 vw` unit is equal to `1%` of the the width of the initial
>   containing block.

Combine it with proper widths for the parent `div` (upto the body and html), and it should give you the desired result. The font-size will then dynamically scale depending on the screen (viewport) size. If you reduce the viewport size, the font-size will decrease and vice-versa.

*For example:*

```
td {
    width: calc(100% / 12); padding: 2px;
    overflow: hidden; background: #bababa;
    font-size: 1.5vw; /* <---- the viewport relative font-size */
}
```

**Demo Fiddle 1: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ucoLcm50/9/**

**Demo Snippet 1 (*click full-screen to see the effect*):**

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
html, body { width: 100%; }
div { background-color: red; width: 50%; min-width: 160px; }
table { width: 100%; font-family: monospace; }
td {
    width: calc(100% / 12); padding: 2px;
    overflow: hidden; background: #bababa;
    font-size: 1.5vw; /* <---- the viewport relative font-size */
}
```

```html
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td><td>A4</td>
            <td>A5</td><td>A6</td><td>A7</td><td>A8</td>
            <td>A9</td><td>A10</td><td>A11</td><td>A12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td><td>B4</td>
            <td>B5</td><td>B6</td><td>B7</td><td>B8</td>
            <td>B9</td><td>B10</td><td>B11</td><td>B12</td>
        </tr>    
    </table>
</div>
```

---

**An alternative** (*and a better*) solution would be to keep the font-size fixed but overflow the containing `div` based on a `min-width`. This will keep the table data readable and also allow a scrollable table when there is a space constraint.

*For example:*

```
div { 
    width: 50%; min-width: 180px; 
    overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: auto;
}
```

**Demo Fiddle 2: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/pu2yh0fc/1/**

**Demo Snippet 2:**

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
html, body { width: 100%; }
div { 
    background-color: red; width: 50%; min-width: 180px; 
    overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: auto;
}
table { min-width: 100%; font-family: monospace; }
td {
    min-width: calc(100% / 12); padding: 2px;
    overflow: hidden; background: #bababa;
    font-size: 1em; 
}
```

```html
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td><td>A4</td>
            <td>A5</td><td>A6</td><td>A7</td><td>A8</td>
            <td>A9</td><td>A10</td><td>A11</td><td>A12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td><td>B4</td>
            <td>B5</td><td>B6</td><td>B7</td><td>B8</td>
            <td>B9</td><td>B10</td><td>B11</td><td>B12</td>
        </tr>    
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Because I mostly need to see a color pattern, and the labels are not as important, your first solution solves that problem greatly.

Answer (score 1):

set the table to width: 100%, and the TDs in the table to 1/12 width (8.3%), then the TDs should resize relative to the table.

```css
table{
    width: 100%;
}
td {
    width:8.3%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #bababa;
}
```

```html
<div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
    </tr>    
</table>
</div>
```

see:

https://jsfiddle.net/ucoLcm50/1/

Comment: The problem if the table needs to get even smaller then the text containing is fixed text size. (See Updated Question, and thanks for your Fiddle)

Comment: setting max-width of 0px seems to work in Chrome (haven't tested in others. See: https://jsfiddle.net/ucoLcm50/10/

Answer (score 0):

How can I have the size dynamically changing, so it always fits the parent div (width: 100%), like an image would?:

See `Jonathans` Solution, Instead of `(1/12)` I'll suggest it should be `(100/no-of-columns[td's] )%` .

should make the font smaller, or at least cut the cells:

add `overflow: hidden;` in your `div's` css (So that it'll hide[cut] cells going out of that div):

```css
div {
    background-color: red;
    width: 50%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
table{
    width:100%;
}
td {
    width:8.3%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #bababa;
}
```

```html
<div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
    </tr>    
</table>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ucoLcm50/5/)

Hope it Helps..