# Best way to display huge 2d array

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, winforms

I want to display `1000x1000` `array` in some way. Array element would either be black or white, depending on boolean value. For this job I am thinking about either `javascript` or `winforms`, but before I jump into, I wanted to hear what could be drawbacks for these choices. I am much more familiar with javascript than winforms though. As for winforms, I tought that there could be too many `GDI` objects to handle. Any ideas, suggestions?

Comment: Does it need to be interactive? How big does each element (square?) have to be? Could you just generate a 1000 x 1000 pixel image with black/white pixels?

Comment: Draw it to a bitmap? Seems like the simplest solution. If you want individual screen elements then yes, that would be more GDI objects than you can have. The more fundamental issue is that a 1000x1000 grid of data is way beyond the comprehension of most people when displayed on a computer screen.

Comment: This will look like an ants race ... What do the booleans express ? Would it make sense to count the number of true / false per "row" and visualize that ?

Comment: User would not interact with it. The size does not matter. I guess I didn't think of bitmap before, because I was going to turn elements on or off (black or white) in loop to see what it draws. But I could try bitmap first, to see if there will be anything to see at all (pixel art, etc.). I wanted to check if there was an easter egg in programming puzzle. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with win-forms but the first idea that came to mind was just a plain old html table. It would be a lot of html though to have 1000 x 1000. Second thing that came to mind would be an SVG. You can manipulate an SVG with JavaScript as shown here http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/scripting.html. Theres also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987005/create-a-table-in-svg) post which shows how to create tables with SVG.You would probably want to generate the SVG before hand to save the application from doing a lot of work and then set the colors using a loop. You can even use photoshop and save as SVG and then open the file in an editor to get the SVG code.