# C3/D3 pie legend format / label overlap

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I have a piechart using C3.
I have changed the default legend names by adding values and percentages and now.

1. I am looking for a way to format this legend nicely so that the values and percentages are positioned like columns.
2. Is there a way to prevent the labels from overlapping?

This is how far I got so far:

```js
var columns = ['data11', 'data2', 'data347', 'data40098'];
var data = [150, 250, 300, 50];
var colors = ['#0065A3', '#767670', '#D73648', '#7FB2CE', '#00345B'];
var padding = 5;

var legendData = [];
var sumTotal = 0

//prepare pie data

var columnData = [];
var columnNames = {};
for (i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
  columnData.push([columns[i]].concat(data[i]));
  var val = (Array.isArray(data[i])) ? data[i].reduce(function(pv, cv) {
    return pv + cv;
  }, 0) : data[i];
  sumTotal += val;
  legendData.push({
    id: columns[i],
    value: val,
    ratio: 0.0
  });
}
legendData.forEach(function(el, i) {
  el.ratio = el.value / sumTotal
  columnNames[el.id] = el.id + ': ' + d3.format(",.0f")(el.value) + " = " + d3.format(",.1%")(el.ratio);
});

var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: d3.select('#chart'),
  data: {
    columns: [
      [columns[0]].concat(data[0])
    ],
    names: columnNames,
    type: 'pie',
  },
  legend: {
    position: 'right',
    show: true
  },
  pie: {
    label: {
      threshold: 0.001,
      format: function(value, ratio, id) {
        return [id, d3.format(",.0f")(value), "[" + d3.format(",.1%")(ratio) + "]"].join(';');
      }
    }
  },
  color: {
    pattern: colors
  },
  onrendered: redrawLabelBackgrounds
});



function addLabelBackground(index) {
  //get label text element
  var textLabel = d3.select(".c3-target-" + columns[index] + " > text");
  //add rect to parent
  var labelNode = textLabel.node();
  if (labelNode /*&& labelNode.innerHTML.length > 0*/ ) {
    var p = d3.select(labelNode.parentNode).insert("rect", "text")
      .style("fill", colors[index]);
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
  if (i > 0) {

    setTimeout(function(column) {
      chart.load({
        columns: [
          columnData[column],
        ]
      });
      //chart.data.names(columnNames[column])
      addLabelBackground(column);

    }, (i * 5000 / columnData.length), i);
  } else {
    addLabelBackground(i);
  }
}


function redrawLabelBackgrounds() {
  //for all label texts drawn yet
  //for all label texts drawn yet
  d3.select('#chart').selectAll(".c3-chart-arc > text").each(function(v) {
    // get d3 node
    var label = d3.select(this);
    var labelNode = label.node();
    //check if label is drawn
    if (labelNode) {
      if (labelNode.childElementCount === 0 && labelNode.innerHTML.length > 0) {
        //build data
        var data = labelNode.innerHTML.split(';');
        label.text("");
        data.forEach(function(i, n) {
          label.append("tspan")
            .text(i)
            .attr("dy", (n === 0) ? 0 : "1.2em")
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle");
        }, label);
      }
      //check if element is visible
      if (d3.select(labelNode.parentNode).style("display") !== 'none') {

        //get pos of the label text
        var pos = label.attr("transform").match(/-?\d+(\.\d+)?/g);
        if (pos) {
          // TODO: mofify the pos of the text
          //            pos[0] = (pos[0]/h*90000);
          //            pos[1] = (pos[1]/h*90000);
          // remove dy and move label
          //d3.select(this).attr("dy", 0);
          //d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + pos[0] + "," + pos[1] + ")");

          //get surrounding box of the label
          var bbox = labelNode.getBBox();

          //now draw and move the rects
          d3.select(labelNode.parentNode).select("rect")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (pos[0] - (bbox.width + padding) / 2) +
              "," + (pos[1] - bbox.height / labelNode.childElementCount) + ")")
            .attr("width", bbox.width + padding)
            .attr("height", bbox.height + padding);
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.6.9/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.6.9/c3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

JSfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/gothmogg/m59poqcd/34/

---

**[edit]**

I have found a bugfix for **flot** fixing the pie label overlap:

```
var label_w = label.width();        //4.3.2014 - from flot user fix #609 on github
var label_h = label.height();       //
var labelTop = (y - label_h / 2);   //
var labelLeft = (x - label_w / 2);  //

//label.css("top", labelTop);       //
//label.css("left", labelLeft);     //

// check to make sure that the label doesn't overlap one of the other labels - 4.3.2014 - from flot user fix #609 on github
var label_pos = [ [ labelLeft, labelLeft + label_w ], [ labelTop, labelTop + label_h ] ];
var newradius = radius;
var bCollision = false;
var yix = 10; //max label reiterations with collisions
do{
for(var j=(labels.length-1); j>=0; j--)
{
    while(comparePositions(label_pos[0], labels[j][0]) && comparePositions(label_pos[1], labels[j][1]))
    {
        newradius -= 2;
        if(newradius < 0.00) {
            break;
        }
        x = centerLeft + Math.round(Math.cos(halfAngle) * newradius);
        y = centerTop + Math.round(Math.sin(halfAngle) * newradius) * options.series.pie.tilt;
        labelTop = (y - label_h / 2);
        labelLeft = (x - label_w / 2);
        label_pos[0][0] = labelLeft;
        label_pos[0][1] = labelLeft + label_w;
        label_pos[1][0] = labelTop;
        label_pos[1][1] = labelTop + label_h;
        bCollision = true;
    }
    if(bCollision) break;
}
label.css("top", labelTop);
label.css("left", labelLeft);
if(bCollision) bCollision = false;
else break;
yix--;
}while(yix>0);

function comparePositions(p1, p2) {
    var x1 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p1 : p2;
    var x2 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p2 : p1;
    return x1[1] > x2[0] || x1[0] === x2[0] ? true : false;
}

labels.push(label_pos);
//end of added code - 4.3.2014 - from flot user fix #609 on github
```

Unfortunately, I do not know how to transfer this fix to C3/D3...

Comment: What do you want it to look like?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I know I can add a custom legend but I want to use the original SVG legendand I added tspans now:

```js
var columns = ['data11', 'data2', 'data347', 'data40091'];
var data = [150, 250, 300, 50];
var colors = ['#0065A3', '#767670', '#D73648', '#7FB2CE', '#00345B'];
var padding = 5;

var legendData = [];
var sumTotal = 0

//prepare pie data

var columnData = [];
var columnNames = {};
for (i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
  columnData.push([columns[i]].concat(data[i]));
  var val = (Array.isArray(data[i])) ? data[i].reduce(function(pv, cv) {
    return pv + cv;
  }, 0) : data[i];
  sumTotal += val;
  legendData.push({
    id: columns[i],
    value: val,
    ratio: 0.0
  });
}
legendData.forEach(function(el, i) {
  el.ratio = el.value / sumTotal
  columnNames[el.id] = [el.id, d3.format(",.0f")(el.value), d3.format(",.1%")(el.ratio)].join(';');
});

var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: d3.select('#chart'),
  data: {
    columns: [
      [columns[0]].concat(data[0])
    ],
    names: columnNames,
    type: 'pie',
  },
  legend: {
    position: 'right',
    show: true
  },
  pie: {
    label: {
      threshold: 0.001,
      format: function(value, ratio, id) {
        return [id, d3.format(",.0f")(value), "[" + d3.format(",.1%")(ratio) + "]"].join(';');
      }
    }
  },
  color: {
    pattern: colors
  },
  onrendered: function() {
    redrawLabelBackgrounds();
    redrawLegend();
  }
});



function addLabelBackground(index) {
  //get label text element
  var textLabel = d3.select(".c3-target-" + columns[index] + " > text");
  //add rect to parent
  var labelNode = textLabel.node();
  if (labelNode /*&& labelNode.innerHTML.length > 0*/ ) {
    var p = d3.select(labelNode.parentNode).insert("rect", "text")
      .style("fill", colors[index]);
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
  if (i > 0) {

    setTimeout(function(column) {
      chart.load({
        columns: [
          columnData[column],
        ]
      });
      //chart.data.names(columnNames[column])
      addLabelBackground(column);

    }, (i * 5000 / columnData.length), i);
  } else {
    addLabelBackground(i);
  }
}

function redrawLegend() {

  d3.select('#chart').selectAll(".c3-legend-item > text").each(function(v) {
    // get d3 node
    var legendItem = d3.select(this);
    legendItem.attr("style", "font-size: 8pt;");
    var legendItemNode = legendItem.node();
    //check if label is drawn
    if (legendItemNode) {
      if (legendItemNode.childElementCount === 0 && legendItemNode.innerHTML.length > 0) {
        //build data
        var data = legendItemNode.innerHTML.split(';');
        legendItem.text("");
        legendItem.append("tspan")
          .text(data[0] + ": ")
          .attr("class", "id-row")
          .attr("text-anchor", "start");
        legendItem.append("tspan")
          .text(data[1] + " = ")
          .attr("class", "value-row")
          .attr("x", 170)
          .attr("text-anchor", "end");
        legendItem.append("tspan")
          .text(data[2])
          .attr("class", "ratio-row")
          .attr("x", 200)
          .attr("text-anchor", "end");

        //.attr("transform", (n === 0) ? "translate(0,0)" : "translate(200,0)")
      }
    }
  });
  d3.select('#chart').selectAll(".c3-legend-item > rect").each(function(v) {
    var legendItem = d3.select(this);
    legendItem.attr("width", 170);
  });

}

function redrawLabelBackgrounds() {
  //for all label texts drawn yet
  d3.select('#chart').selectAll(".c3-chart-arc > text").each(function(v) {
    // get d3 node
    var label = d3.select(this);
    var labelNode = label.node();
    //check if label is drawn
    if (labelNode) {
      if (labelNode.childElementCount === 0 && labelNode.innerHTML.length > 0) {
        //build data
        var data = labelNode.innerHTML.split(';');
        label.text("");
        data.forEach(function(i, n) {
          label.append("tspan")
            .text(i)
            .attr("dy", (n === 0) ? 0 : "1.2em")
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle");
        }, label);
      }
      //check if element is visible
      if (d3.select(labelNode.parentNode).style("display") !== 'none') {

        //get pos of the label text
        var pos = label.attr("transform").match(/-?\d+(\.\d+)?/g);
        if (pos) {
          // TODO: mofify the pos of the text
          //            pos[0] = (pos[0]/h*90000);
          //            pos[1] = (pos[1]/h*90000);
          // remove dy and move label
          //d3.select(this).attr("dy", 0);
          //d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + pos[0] + "," + pos[1] + ")");

          //get surrounding box of the label
          var bbox = labelNode.getBBox();

          //now draw and move the rects
          d3.select(labelNode.parentNode).select("rect")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (pos[0] - (bbox.width + padding) / 2) +
              "," + (pos[1] - bbox.height / labelNode.childElementCount) + ")")
            .attr("width", bbox.width + padding)
            .attr("height", bbox.height + padding);
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.6.9/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.6.9/c3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart">

</div>
```

This solves the Problem #1 to 98% ;)

Now I only need to figue our how to calculate the width of the spans dynamically depending on the content the most elegant way.

(and #2 of course)

Comment: I do not understand why an answer to my own question can be not useful. This perfectly fits the need of a custom legend and this legend still has the C3 chart functionallity like mouseover and click events used in C3.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to create a [custom legend](https://c3js.org/samples/legend_custom.html). Then you can create & style it as you like in either SVG or HTML.

```js
var columns = ['data11', 'data2', 'data347', 'data40098'];
var data = [150, 250, 300, 50];
var colors = ['#0065A3', '#767670', '#D73648', '#7FB2CE', '#00345B'];
var padding = 5;

var legendData = [];
var sumTotal = 0

//prepare pie data

var columnData = [];
var columnNames = {};
for (i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
  columnData.push([columns[i]].concat(data[i]));
  var val = (Array.isArray(data[i])) ? data[i].reduce(function(pv, cv) {
    return pv + cv;
  }, 0) : data[i];
  sumTotal += val;
  legendData.push({
    id: columns[i],
    value: val,
    ratio: 0.0
  });
}
legendData.forEach(function(el, i) {
  el.ratio = el.value / sumTotal
  columnNames[el.id] = el.id + ': ' + d3.format(",.0f")(el.value) + " = " + d3.format(",.1%")(el.ratio);
});

var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: d3.select('#chart'),
  data: {
    columns: [
      [columns[0]].concat(data[0])
    ],
    names: columnNames,
    type: 'pie',
  },
  legend: {
    position: 'right',
    show: false
  },
  pie: {
    label: {
      threshold: 0.001,
      format: function(value, ratio, id) {
        return [id, d3.format(",.0f")(value), "[" + d3.format(",.1%")(ratio) + "]"].join(';');
      }
    }
  },
  color: {
    pattern: colors
  },
  onrendered: redrawLabelBackgrounds
});



function addLabelBackground(index) {
  //get label text element
  var textLabel = d3.select(".c3-target-" + columns[index] + " > text");
  //add rect to parent
  var labelNode = textLabel.node();
  if (labelNode /*&& labelNode.innerHTML.length > 0*/ ) {
    var p = d3.select(labelNode.parentNode).insert("rect", "text")
      .style("fill", colors[index]);
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
  if (i > 0) {

    setTimeout(function(column) {
      chart.load({
        columns: [
          columnData[column],
        ]
      });
      //chart.data.names(columnNames[column])
      addLabelBackground(column);

    }, (i * 5000 / columnData.length), i);
  } else {
    addLabelBackground(i);
  }
}


function redrawLabelBackgrounds() {
  //for all label texts drawn yet
  //for all label texts drawn yet
  d3.select('#chart').selectAll(".c3-chart-arc > text").each(function(v) {
    // get d3 node
    var label = d3.select(this);
    var labelNode = label.node();
    //check if label is drawn
    if (labelNode) {
      if (labelNode.childElementCount === 0 && labelNode.innerHTML.length > 0) {
        //build data
        var data = labelNode.innerHTML.split(';');
        label.text("");
        data.forEach(function(i, n) {
          label.append("tspan")
            .text(i)
            .attr("dy", (n === 0) ? 0 : "1.2em")
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle");
        }, label);
      }
      //check if element is visible
      if (d3.select(labelNode.parentNode).style("display") !== 'none') {

        //get pos of the label text
        var pos = label.attr("transform").match(/-?\d+(\.\d+)?/g);
        if (pos) {
          // TODO: mofify the pos of the text
          //            pos[0] = (pos[0]/h*90000);
          //            pos[1] = (pos[1]/h*90000);
          // remove dy and move label
          //d3.select(this).attr("dy", 0);
          //d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + pos[0] + "," + pos[1] + ")");

          //get surrounding box of the label
          var bbox = labelNode.getBBox();

          //now draw and move the rects
          d3.select(labelNode.parentNode).select("rect")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (pos[0] - (bbox.width + padding) / 2) +
              "," + (pos[1] - bbox.height / labelNode.childElementCount) + ")")
            .attr("width", bbox.width + padding)
            .attr("height", bbox.height + padding);
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

//console.log(columnData)


function toggle(id) {
  chart.toggle(id);
}

var table = d3.select('#chart')
  .append('table').attr('class', 'legend')

var row = table.selectAll('row').data(columnData)
var rowEnter = row.enter().append('tr').attr('class', 'legend-row')
rowEnter.append('td').attr('style', (d, i) => `width: 20px;background-color:${colors[i]}`)
rowEnter.append('td').text(d => d[0])
rowEnter.append('td').text(d => d[1])


rowEnter.on('mouseover', function(id) {
  if (!this.classList.contains('legend-row-disabled')) {
    rowEnter.classed('legend-row-inactive', true)
    chart.focus(id);
  }

});

rowEnter.on('mouseout', function(id) {
  rowEnter.classed('legend-row-inactive', false)
  if (!this.classList.contains('legend-row-disabled')) {
    chart.focus()
  }
})

rowEnter.on('click', function(id) {
  chart.toggle(id);
  this.classList.toggle('legend-row-disabled');
  chart.focus()

});
```

```css
.legend {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.legend .legend-row {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.legend .legend-row td:first-child {
  width: 14px !important;
}

.legend .legend-row.legend-row-inactive {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.legend .legend-row.legend-row-inactive:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.legend .legend-row.legend-row-disabled,
.legend .legend-row.legend-row-disabled:hover {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.legend td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.6.9/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.6.9/c3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart">

</div>
```

Comment: Added some style and addition mouse actions to emulate the legend a bit more. https://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/aqvr3f8x/

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Polywhirl. Mind if I add those additions to this answer?

Comment: Go ahead. They add more functionality, but hovering over a hidden item is a bit tricky.

Comment: I know I can add a custom legend but I qas trying to use the original SVG legend.
I added tspans now: http://jsfiddle.net/gothmogg/zhep4s0r/31/

Now I only need to figue our how to calculate the width of the spans dynamically depending on the content the most elegant way.

Comment: So do you want to recreate a table in svg?

Comment: I do not necessarily want to have a real table. It does only have to be positioned like it would be a table, positioned in rows.
In the example with tspans above I used fixed widths for each tspan "row"... This not optimal as the width would need to change if the values get bigger or smaller.

Comment: Ok, maybe not a real table. But do you want to emulate what a table does only using svg? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987005/create-a-table-in-svg

Comment: can you maybe just have a look at my jsfiddle where I use d3 to get pretty close to where I want?
I now only need an elegant way to dynamically format/size the tspans

Comment: Ask another question and link to it here.

Comment: I have added my question about dynamically sizing the tspans here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54783106/sizing-custom-c3-piechart-legend-dynamically-using-d3