# Transform HTML table to SVG?

Tags: python, css-tables, adobe-indesign

I have to generate weekly a set of reports. This reports include some tables and to generate them we are using Excel. I want to get rid of Excel because of the crashes and lack of performance.The format of the tables I want to generate is similar to this one:

[image: Table to generate]

I taught that a good idea would be to generate this tables in HTML with CSS because then I could automatically generate the strings with Python, creating the HTML files. The code I made is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<!-- This block is to generate CSS for the document. -->
<head>
<style>
.header {
    font-weight:700pt;
    color:#164875;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.panelist-header {
    border-bottom:.5pt solid #164B75;
    text-align:left;
    color:#164875;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color:white;
}

.year-header {
    border-bottom:.5pt solid #164B75;
    text-align:right;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color:white;
}

.panelist {
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.value {
    text-align:right;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

table {
    height: 16px;
        font-size:9pt;
        font-weight:400pt;
        font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border:0;
        cellpadding:0;
        cellspacing:0;
        width:320px;
}

/* This creates the zebra effect. */
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #EAEAEA;
}  
</style>
</head>

<!-- Here we define the table. -->
<body>
<table>
   <colgroup>
      <col width="184">
      <col span="2" width="68">
   </colgroup>
   <tr height="24" class="header" style="background-color:white">
      <th></th>
      <th colspan="2">Indicator<br>variation in %</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th class="panelist-header"><b>Individual Forecasts</b></th>
      <th class="year-header"><b>2023</b></th>
      <th class="year-header"><b>2024</b></th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="panelist">Panelist1</td>
      <td class="value">0.5</td>
      <td class="value">1.8</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="panelist">Panelist2</td>
      <td class="value">0.7</td>
      <td class="value">1.3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="panelist">Panelist3</td>
      <td class="value">0.4</td>
      <td class="value">1.5</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th class="panelist-header"><b>Public Forecasts</b></th>
      <th class="year-header"><b></b></th>
      <th class="year-header"><b></b></th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="panelist">Panelist4</td>
      <td class="value">1.0</td>
      <td class="value">1.3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th class="panelist-header"><b>Summary</b></th>
      <th class="year-header"><b></b></th>
      <th class="year-header"><b></b></th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="panelist">Minimum</td>
      <td class="value">-1.3</td>
      <td class="value">0.3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="panelist">Maximum</td>
      <td class="value">1.8</td>
      <td class="value">2.6</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="panelist">Median</td>
      <td class="value">0.6</td>
      <td class="value">1.5</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="panelist"><b>Consensus</b></td>
      <td class="value"><b>0.4</b></td>
      <td class="value"><b>1.5</b></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th class="panelist-header"><b>History</b></th>
      <th class="year-header"><b></b></th>
      <th class="year-header"><b></b></th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="panelist">30 days ago</td>
      <td class="value">0.4</td>
      <td class="value">1.5</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="panelist">60 days ago</td>
      <td class="value">0.4</td>
      <td class="value">1.6</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="panelist">90 days ago</td>
      <td class="value">0.7</td>
      <td class="value">1.8</td>
   </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see is a very simple HTML document that includes some CSS that woud allow me to costumize the tables depending on the number of panelists I have in my data.

However, I found that now I have this but I don't know how to obtein a suitable format to fit into InDesign (the tool that we use to generate the reports).

Hence my questions are:

- There is a way to transform this HTML file to a more suitable format? Preferibly a vectorized format as an SVG.
- There is a better way of generating this kind of tables programatically? Maybe replicating the same structure directly with SVG?

Comment: You can convert it to PDF if you want. You can do this for example by cmdline tools like [electron-pdf](https://github.com/fraserxu/electron-pdf), or headless chrome. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533886/is-there-a-command-line-tool-for-converting-html-files-to-pdf) for more examples of software

Comment: Is InDesign only accept SVG? Any other format does it accept? I don't think show a table by SVG is a good idea.

Comment: This maybe helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987005/create-a-table-in-svg